# Html Agility Pack return Null for a Nodecollection

Tags: html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse a PHP page which contain many tables. Now when I try to select those tables, the collection return null?

```
    Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb()
    Dim htmlDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = web.Load("URL")
    Dim html As String

    Dim tabletag As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")
    Dim tableNode As HtmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@summary='List of services']")

    If Not tabletag Is Nothing Then
    html = tableNode.InnerText

    End If
```

This page certainly has some tables, Just dont understand why it returns null for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loaded your URL up in a browser and viewed the source and there actually aren't any tables that I could find. Wrong URL?

Comment: Thats weird. This is the link again


http://www.scswis.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=7644&Itemid=489&bereNextPageId=ServiceList_action.php&action=movePaging&offset=10

Comment: Nope, no HTML <table> elements. Where on the page do you find tables? Are you perhaps interacting with the page in the browser, which results in it loading another page that contains tables? Or, interacting with the page, which results in it loading HTML containing tables into the DOM on-the-fly? Keep in mind that the Agility Pack will only parse what you give it, and it doesn't do that magic that your browser and JavaScript might be doing.

Comment: Okay I realised what is going wrong! In order to receive that table I went through a form and clicked "Submit" button and then got redirected to that page. Obviously using that link directly does not result in accessing the table. This is tricky for me though. I don't know how I'm suppose to do that! Using httpwebrequest maybe ? but then would I be able to use htmlagilitypack since I need to pass a URL web.load ?

Comment: This is the page, If you click on submit button it will take you to the tables


http://www.scswis.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=7644&Itemid=489#

Comment: Ok, I see the issue now. What you need to do is mimic the browser's submission of the form via POST, and then you'll be able to parse out the tables in the resulting HTML that is returned. You can submit the form and get the response via HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse, and then parse with the Agility Pack, or do everything with the Agility Pack. I found a blog entry that should get you started (and you can probably find others via Google as well): http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out that I have to use a post method with httpwebrequest and managed to get it working. However I like the way it has been done in the link you posted, so I will give it try that way as well. Cheers